# Extjs searchfield Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the next store:

```
Ext.define('Invoices.store.Invoice', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'Invoices.model.Invoice',
alias: 'store.InvoiceStore',


remoteFilter: false,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/invoices/filter',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
},

autoLoad: false
});
```

and this model:

```
Ext.define('Invoices.model.Invoice', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['data']
});
```

When I call this compnent from a view, the error shown:

```
{
    xtype: 'searchfield',
    name: 'client',
    store: 'InvoiceStore',
    fieldLabel: 'Cliente<b><span style="color: #d32f2f">*</span></b>'
},

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
```

And this happen  in the next line of code from SearchField component main class:

```
if (!me.store.proxy.hasOwnProperty('filterParam')) {
        me.store.proxy.filterParam = me.paramName;
}
```

I supposed it happens because of null reference passed to the component, maybe the store, but I changed the alias and the model and nothing happen yet, the same error is still shown.

Any help? Any Idea? Do I deserve to be fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you aren't creating the store instance anywhere. If you're just passing a string, it means it's the id of an already existing store. If you want to create the store by alias (which is what I think you're trying to do), then you need to specify it like so:

```
store: {
    type: 'InvoiceStore'
}
```